# How can I select a Specific list of tags when using Beautiful soup 4?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying my hand at web scraping and I decided to make a script that takes the information from job listings from the python website. My code when it comes to scraping the information from a job listing works and the only thing that I have trouble solving is how I can iterate through the job listings. The jobs listings are enclosed in their < li > tags but there are also < li > tags at the top of the page. How can I iterate through the group of Tags that I want instead of the ones at the top.

I tried using a for loop to iterate through the < li > tags that I searched for using the find_all method

```
# 1. get website
url  = 'https://www.python.org/jobs/'
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
website = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'lxml')

jobs = soup.find_all('li')

counter = 0


for listing in jobs:

    # 2. get info
    job = listing.find('span', class_ = "listing-company-name")
    job_type = listing.find('span', class_ = "listing-job-type")
    job_location = listing.find('span', class_ = "listing-location")

    # 3. display info

    print(f'Job Title: {job.a.text}')
    print(f'Company: {job.br.next_sibling.strip()}')
    print(f'Skills Needed: {job_type.text}')
    print(f'Location: {job_location.text}')
```

The problem is that it returns None when I try to find the specific class because it searches the < li > tags at the top of the page which contain the titles and headers of the website itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way, first find all the `span` tags with the class you need, and then select the desired text from it in a loop.

```
import bs4
import requests


# 1. get website
url  = 'https://www.python.org/jobs/'
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
website = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(website.status_code)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'lxml')

jobs = soup.find_all('span', class_ = "listing-company-name")

job_text = [job.a.text for job in jobs]

print(f'Job Title: {job_text}')
```

The rest are similar.